# dynamically created checkbox marked/unmarked based on values from different table in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, checkbox, eloquent

I have a table 'roles'

[image]

And another table 'role_users'

[image]

I have a dynamically generated checkboxes from 'roles' like this: [image]

How can I show the checkboxes that are retrieved from 'roles' table marked/unmarked based on values from 'role_users' for corresponding 'user_id'?

I have this in my view:

```
{!! Form::open(['url' =>URL::to('admin/user/'.$profileUser->id) , 'method'=>'PUT', 'enctype'=>'multipart/form-data' ]) !!}
                    @foreach ($userRoles as $key => $userRole)
                    <tr>
                        <td width="10%">{{ Form::label($userRole->name) }}</td>
                        <td>{{ Form::checkbox( 'rolename[]', $userRole->id) }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    @endforeach
                    <tr>{{ Form::submit('Save', array('class' => 'btn', 'name' => 'roleSubmit')) }}</tr>
            </tbody>
            {{ Form::close() }}
```

where:

```
$userRoles = DB::table('roles')->get();
```

How can I show the checkboxes that are retrieved from 'roles' table marked/unmarked based on values from 'role_users' for corresponding 'user_id'?

Comment: What's your requirement.? Please be specific

Comment: I want to show checkboxes (that are being generated from values of table 'role') marked/unmarked based on values in 'role_users' table, for 'user_id'=3117

Comment: You need to `eager load` roles and permissions to the specified user.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
   $role_id = 1;
?>
```

---

```
<table>
<tr>
<td> 
    <input type='checkbox' <?php if($role_id == 0) {echo 'checked' ;} ?> >Admin<br/>
    <input type='checkbox' <?php if($role_id == 1) {echo 'checked' ;} ?> >CIO<br/>
    <input type='checkbox' <?php if($role_id == 2) {echo 'checked' ;} ?> >IO<br/>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It would serve my purpose if I had 3 fixed roles. Admin, CIO and IO. But my app has the ability to create new roles. So the roles table value is variable. and therefore I have to check dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a third parameter to mark it checked or not.

{{ Form::checkbox('agree', 1, true) }}

so I think you need to make a condition on the third parameter.

---

```
 @foreach ($userRoles as $key => $userRole)
                <tr>
                    <td width="10%">{{ Form::label($userRole->name) }}</td>
                    <td>{{ Form::checkbox( 'rolename[]', $userRole->id, (bool) $userRole->id == $profileUser->role_id }}</td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
```

---

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to tell about the function `Form::checkbox()` which is creating your html render.

Edit: OK so you have a master table that has all the roles and a user table which has a foreign key to this master table, correct?

if so you can loop over `$userRoles` and for each user make a nested loop (over `$roles`, which will be a separate master array), for each `$role`(in `$roles`) check if it is equal to the `$userRole`(of `$userRoles`), if they are same the box will checked, if not it will be unchecked.